# GitHub For Windows missing open in Visual Studio button

Tags: git, github-desktop

The "Open In Visual Studio" button that allows you to launch Visual Studio is missing when Visual Studio 2017 is installed.  Here is an example of it working:

[image]

I looked into using the successor of this application, GitHub Desktop, but it doesn't support this feature as of now.

How do I get this button to appear?

Comment: Link to issue: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/2703

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub for Windows relies on a Visual Studio 2015 registry entry in order to enable the button.  Since only Visual Studio 2017 was installed, this registry entry doesn't exist.  Here is the content of my enable_vs_githug.reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.DTE.14.0]
@="Microsoft Visual Studio DTE Object"
```

Run the reg file and restart github desktop, no system reboot needed.

Comment: Tried this but did not help me.

Comment: I just recently did a fresh install of windows and Visual Studio 2017 and it works.  I edited my answer explaining how to create a reg file which will hopefully make it easier to use.